# Como hacer una funcion que regrese del 1 al 9 si el argumento es mayor a 9 en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

si a una función le paso un numero e.g.: 1 me retornara 1 y así hasta el nueve,
si a esa función le paso un 10 debería de retornarse el 1 ejemplos:
input:10 output:1, input:11 output:2 ...
realice esta función, pero en algunos numero por ejemplo los que terminan en 9, me imprime 10

```
function resetnum(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        console.log(num);
    } else {
        var temp = (num % 10) + 1;
        console.log(temp);
    }

}
```

que debería hacer para que por ejemplo en 19 me regrese a 1

Comment: `num % 9` siempre te va a devolver un número entre 0 y 9, por ejemplo. No hay necesidad de mirar si es menor a 10 o no. Eso si, devuelve de 0 a 9, no de 1 a 9 :)

Comment: 19 % 10 es 9, por lo que no te regresaría el resultado que esperas. Pero si pudieras poner una tabla de entradas y salidas de lo que necesitas conseguir con gusto te ayudo

Comment: Hola, intente esta funcion
function resetnum(num) {
 return num%10;
}
pero en 10 me regresa 0, la sucesion es 
1->1 
... 
9->9.....

10->1,
11->2,
12->3,
13->4

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es algo tonta pero si no sabia por donde, gracias por su apoyo. dejo como quedo la función

```
function resetnum(num) {
return num % 9 == 0 ? 9 : num % 9;}
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu pregunta no dices qué sucede para el caso en que se reciba un valor menor que 1, en mi respuesta tampoco ataco completamente este caso, aunque sólo muestro cómo tomar en cuenta el caso particular en que el resto de la división entre el valor recibido es exacto.

El resto de la división entera entre dos números se calcula usando el operador `%`, conocido "popularmente" como `módulo`.

Tu deseas que se devuelvan los valores entre 1 y 9 para cualquier valor recibido por tu función, de tal forma que se pueda establecer una relación o mapeo de la siguiente forma:

```
 1 =>  1
 2 =>  2
   ...
 8 =>  8
 9 =>  9
10 =>  1
11 =>  2
   ...
17 =>  8
18 =>  9
19 =>  1
20 =>  2
   ...
```

Parece un sistema numérico de 9 caracteres pero en ausencia del cero. Además, la correspondencia empieza en el valor 1 de los decimales, por lo cual tal vez se trate del conjunto de los números Naturales como dominio o conjunto de partida.

Una función muy sencilla que hace el trabajo es la siguiente:

```js
function resetnum(num) {
  if(num % 9 === 0) return 9;
  return (num % 9);
}

let numeros = [1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 17, 18, 19];

for(let num of numeros) {
  console.log(resetnum(num));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, estoy tomando en cuenta el caso en que el resto de la división da cero, y cuando esto sucede se devuelve 9.

Como sabemos, el resto de una división entera nunca puede ser mayor al valor del divisor, es decir, si divido `m` entre `n`, el resto siempre será de magnitud máxima `n-1`. Dicho de otra manera, el resto de la división entera de `m` entre `n` estará siempre entre 0 y `n-1`.

Es por ello que al realizar la división entera de cualquier número natural entre 9, obtendremos un resto entre 0 y 8.

Debido a que nuestro *mapeo* no incluye el 0, el mismo lo sustituyo por el 9, de esta forma se cumple la relación establecida como condición.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

`num % 9` devuelve el [resto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) luego de dividir por 9, que siempre es un número entre 0 y 8.

Si le restamos 1 antes de sacar el resto, y le sumamos 1 luego, siempre vas a obtener un número entre 1 y 9, de modo que se mantenga el primer rango de de 1 a 9 sin modificar.

```js
function entre1y9(num) {
  return (num - 1) % 9 + 1;
}


//Prueba
let x = prompt("Número:"),

    resultado = entre1y9(x);
  
console.log('Número:', x,'Resultado:', resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

yo hice esta función que elimina el último o últimos dijitos y devuelve solo el primero, no se si es así que deseas que sea pero, espero te ayude.

Aunque no devuelve como el ejemplo que hiciste sobre sumar uno eje. Input 11, output 2. En ese casi modificaría lo que devuelve, más 1.

```js
function resetnum(num) {
  
  if(num < 10) {
    console.log(num)
  } else {
    var bs= num.toString()
    var newnum = bs.split('')
    console.log(newnum[0])
  }
}
```